# Fill a plist with quotes

Tags: iphone, xcode, random, plist

I have been doing some work for a while on an iPhone daily quote app, and the bulk of comments I received are to use a plist to store the quotes, and then setup the code to randomly access a quote each day.  I have never really worked with a plist though, and am unsure as to the best way to build a new one filled with quotes.  Could I get some guidance on this?

Comment: I'm working on a similar app that I want it to do just this. Can you show me how you did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plist could look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>A Quote</string>
    <string>A Quote</string>
    <string>A Quote</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

You can open a plist into an array like this. You'd then have an array of strings that you could do whatever you want with. Once you have an array I assume you know how to get a random object from it.

```
[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"myPlist.plist"];
```

Comment: Thanks, just one other thing was needing...never built a plist before, so in Xcode I do New file, choose plist, but not sure what kind of type it should be.  Do I just leave it as Default and then add a row as the array, and under that row put in all the quotes?

Comment: If you're doing it in Xcode then each row is a quote. The whole plist is an array. So if you were to make a row as an array then have subrows under that you'd technically have an array in an array. If that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so I all I need to do is create the plist, then add one row of a string for each quote?  Makes sense

Comment: Yep that should do it. You can get much more complicated with nested arrays, dictionaries, and more but this should definitely get you started. Thankfully NSArray has a built in parser so all you need is that one line of code to automatically read the plist.

Comment: One problem I am getting is that it is returning null for the array.  Here is how the plist looks.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Quotes</key>
  <array>
  <string>`

Comment: Its because of the dict part. That will return a dictionary. YOu can either change your plist to be an array or you can do `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"myPlist.plist"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>files</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Resources/Info.plist</key>
        <data>
        OkWU6AfEeAr3G1LVjwgv3QVl/C4=
        </data>
    </dict>
    <key>files2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Resources/Info.plist</key>
        <dict>
            <key>hash</key>
            <data>
            OkWU6AfEeAr3G1LVjwgv3QVl/C4=
            </data>
            <key>hash2</key>
            <data>
            bTnXxa3Ed3AQ3vCPs76DvwtUwOlgsWxMGNleo3ICfKA=
            </data>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>rules</key>
    <dict>
        <key>^Resources/</key>
        <true/>
        <key>^Resources/.*\.lproj/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>optional</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1000</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/.*\.lproj/locversion.plist$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>omit</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1100</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/Base\.lproj/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1010</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^version.plist$</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>rules2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>.*\.dSYM($|/)</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>11</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^(.*/)?\.DS_Store$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>omit</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>2000</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^(Frameworks|SharedFrameworks|PlugIns|Plug-ins|XPCServices|Helpers|MacOS|Library/(Automator|Spotlight|LoginItems))/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>nested</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>10</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^.*</key>
        <true/>
        <key>^Info\.plist$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>omit</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>20</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^PkgInfo$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>omit</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>20</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>20</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/.*\.lproj/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>optional</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1000</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/.*\.lproj/locversion.plist$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>omit</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1100</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^Resources/Base\.lproj/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>1010</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^[^/]+$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>nested</key>
            <true/>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>10</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^embedded\.provisionprofile$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>20</real>
        </dict>
        <key>^version\.plist$</key>
        <dict>
            <key>weight</key>
            <real>20</real>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.